# Javascript functionality not working properly on my regex

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I can't seem to figure out where in my code is wrong, if it is my regex or my code in javascript. When I input the correct email format, the alert is still coming when it is supposed to come out only when the email format is wrong.

I am using the toggleClass functionality of javascript for the alerts in an active modal.

```js
$('.email').blur(function() {
  var regex =
    /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
  var isEmailCorrect = $(this).val().match(regex);
  $('.modal:visible').find('.popemail').toggleClass('hide', isEmailCorrect);
  $('.sub').prop('disabled', !isEmailCorrect);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<label>Email</label>
<span id="popover-email" class="popemail hide pull-right block-help">
    <i class="fa fa-info-circle text-danger" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    Please use the proper format of an email</span>
<input type="email" class="email form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" value="<?php echo $row['email']; ?>">
```

When an email is placed with proper format there should be no alert to come out, but when wrong format of email is placed then the alert should come out. I used toggle class for the alert, see line #4.

Comment: Can you provide a full working example that can be run & used here?

Comment: wait, let me add the html code

Comment: You've told us the expected result but what's actually happening?

Comment: @frobinsonj I updated my problem

Answer (score 3):

You are using `.match()` which will return an array of matched substrings in your regex.  This is not a boolean value.  Run this example to see:

```js
var regex =/^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;

console.log("bob@aol.com".match(regex));
```

What you want instead if yo use `.test()` which will return a boolean if it matches or not.

```js
var regex =/^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;

console.log(regex.test("bob@aol.com"));
console.log(regex.test("banana"));
```

---

### EDIT:

To be clear, this is what your code should be.  I've added some debugging `console.log` calls to help you see what things are.  I've changed the HTML a bit just to make this demo work.  Click the "Run code snippet" button.

```js
$('.email').blur(function() {
  var regex = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
  
  var isEmailCorrect = regex.test(this.value);
  
  console.log('Email Value:', this.value);
  console.log('Is Email Correct:', isEmailCorrect);
  
  $('.modal:visible').find('.popemail').toggleClass('hide', isEmailCorrect);
  $('.sub').prop('disabled', !isEmailCorrect);
});
```

```css
.hide{display:none;}
.popover-email{color: red;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="modal">
  <label for="email">Email</label>
  <input type="email" id="email" class="email" name="email" placeholder="Email">
  <span id="popover-email" class="hide popemail">Please use the proper format of an email</span>
</div>
```

Comment: sir I edited my code using .test but nothing came out

Comment: make sure you are doing `regext.test('email')` and **not** `'email'.test(regex)` - I always get this mixed up.  Refer to the working code examples in my answer here, run them to see the console output.

Comment: Okay thanks it worked but still I cant get the expected output. here is my code var isEmailCorrect = regex.test($(this));
                $('.modal:visible').find('.popemail').toggleClass('hide', !isEmailCorrect);
                $('.sub').prop('disabled', isEmailCorrect);

Comment: You are testing the entire jQuery selector, you need to test the text value inside it.  `isEmailCorrect = regex.test($(this).val());` or even `isEmailCorrect = regex.test(this.value);`

Comment: FYI, you can easily debug things by logging things to the console.  to find out what you are passing in might not be what you expect.  `console.log($(this))` would have easily told you that it's the entire HTML element instead of the string value of the element where as  `console.log($(this).val())` will show you the value you want to test against

Comment: See my updated answer with an additional runnable code snippet

Answer (score 0):

Your original expression works just fine, maybe you might want to trim your inputs before testing it, might pass some spaces that would conflict with start and end anchors, or maybe you are passing some chars that are not allowed:

```
^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$
```

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/nD9wFo/1/)

```js
const regex = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/gm;
const str = `alice@google.com
bob@google.com
alice@google_.com
bob@google.co_
`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }
    
    // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
    m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
        console.log(`Found match, group ${groupIndex}: ${match}`);
    });
}
```

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @Chris Barr you should use [Regexp#test](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) method instead of [String#match](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match). So you have to change only one row in your code:

```
  var isEmailCorrect = regex.test($(this).val());
```

After that you have to debug in console your jQuery selectors, because of using your html element with class 'modal' could not be found anymore.